# How do I use OLE-DB to access a dbf file in an COM/C++ ATL application?

Tags: c++, com, oledb, atl, dbf

How to access the data contained in a dbf file in COM/C++ application (created via ATL)?

Answer (score 1):

I would use ADO; it's by far the quickest way to get going, even with dealing with the COM aspects of it. Start [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675532(VS.85).aspx). It's much easier than rolling your own Consumer implementation, unless you really need to lower-level access that doing OLEDB directly provides.